# saving output of nettop to file ( mac )

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

I'm trying to save the output of nettop from my terminal to a text file ( maybe .csv ) what I want to do is be able to isolate the different values, specifically I want to track the bytes coming in from a particular application ( so that i can reference that file in another application ) I'm not very familiar with bash scripting but I imagine the right script could accomplish this sort of thing, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You want the `-L` option. `nettop -L 1`, for example, will output a single sample in `.csv` format which will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

You can redirect the output of any terminal program to a file using the `>` character.  in the terminal try:
  `nettop > output.txt`

that will save the output of nettop to the file output.txt.  If you want to view the output from nettop and save it at the same time, try this:
  `nettop | tee output.txt`

that will "pipe" the output to the program "tee" which will print it to the terminal and write it to the file.

Comment: This does not work because `nettop` is a `curses` program that emits terminal codes. Luckily there's an option to get what the OP wants (see my answer)